# Как при открытие страницы сделать так чтоб она открылась на определенной позиции?

Tags: javascript, html

у меня вопрос.
Как сделать так чтоб при открытие страницы она открылась на определенной позиции?
Например по середине, как на фото.

[image]

Comment: можно через js имитировать скролл на определенную позицию..

Comment: К WordPress отношения не имеет

Comment: Да, вы правы, добавил по причине работы с WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться "якорем".
Материалы (в данном случае вопросы) должны иметь определённый атрибут `id`

Например: `<div id="XYZ">...</div>`

И при переходе на ссылку с указанием якоря, будете перемещаться к нему,
например:
`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions#XYZ`

Для плавности перемещения можно будет использовать JS.

Answer (score 0):

используйте в ссылке якорь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest#related-tags
где **related-tags** - id элемента, указывается после символа "#" как в ссылке выше

Answer (score 0):

Прокручивает вниз на 500px

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Пример для плавной прокрутки вниз на 100px от верха:

```js
window.scrollTo({
    top: 100,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```